# Pandas - Calculate New Value Based on Cross Reference with Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining, cross-reference

I'm trying to calculate new values in a column whose values are cross-referenced to another column.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {"A":[0., 100., 80., 40., 0., 60.], 
                        "B":[12,  12,   3,  19,  3,  19]} )
>>> df
       A   B
0    0.0  12
1  100.0  12
2   80.0   3
3   40.0  19
4    0.0   3
5   60.0  19
```

I want to find all values in column A that are 0, find out the corresponding value in column B, then change all column A values that have the same column B value, according to some function. For instance in the example above I would like to change the first two values of column A, `df.A[0]` and `df.A[1]`, respectively 0. and 100., into 0.5 and 99.5, because `df.A[0]` is 0. and it has the same value `df.B[0] = 12` in column B as `df.B[1] = 12`.

```
df
      A   B
0   0.5  12
1  99.5  12
2  79.5   3
3  40.0  19
4   0.5   3
5  60.0  19
```

I tried chaining loc, aggregate, groupby and mask functionalities, but I'm not succeeding. Is the only way through a for loop?

---

EDIT:
Broadened example to better illustrate intent.

Comment: What function do you want to apply?

Comment: How did you calculate the values `0.5` and `99.5`, there has to be some logic behind it.

Comment: @gmds, the most elementary function would be: if value=0 then calculated value = 0.5 and cross referenced value = previous value - 0.5

Comment: @gciriani so is it guaranteed that where `df[A]==0`, all values of `df[B]` are the same?

Comment: @gmds, yes for now where df[A]==0, all values of df[B] are the same; in future I may have to change the function, but I'll cross that bridge when necessary.

Comment: @Erfan, see comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, although probably sub-optimal. I chain groupby, filter and transform to obtain a desired series, and then replace the result in the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A":[0., 100., 80., 40., 0., 60.], 
                    "B":[12,  12,   3,  19,  3,  19]} )
u = ( df.groupby(by="B",  sort=False)
         .filter(lambda x: x.A.min() == 0, dropna=False)
         .A.transform( lambda x: (x+0.5).where(x == 0, x - 0.5) ) 
    )
df.loc[pd.notnull(u), "A"] = u
```

gives the following results

```
print("\ninitial df\n",df,"\n\nintermediate series\n",u,"\n\nfinal result",df)

initial df
        A   B
0    0.0  12
1  100.0  12
2   80.0   3
3   40.0  19
4    0.0   3
5   60.0  19

intermediate series
 0     0.5
1    99.5
2    79.5
3     NaN
4     0.5
5     NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64

final result       A   B
0   0.5  12
1  99.5  12
2  79.5   3
3  40.0  19
4   0.5   3
5  60.0  19
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"A":[0., 100., 40., 60.], "B":[12, 12, 19, 19]} )

def f(series):
    return (series + 0.5).where(series == 0, series - 0.5)

B_value = df.loc[df['A'] == 0, 'B'][0]
df.loc[df['B'] == B_value, 'A'] = df.loc[df['B'] == B_value, 'A'].transform(f)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      A   B
0   0.5  12
1  99.5  12
2  40.0  19
3  60.0  19
```

You can pass an arbitrary function into `transform`.

There might be a cleaner way to do this; it strikes me as slightly messy.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be scaling to the whole data frame. If there is more than one 0.0 value it doesn't work. For instance when the starting df has a 0.0 in the location where there is now 60.0, the result for column A is [0.5, 99.5, 40.0, 0.0]; I instead aim to obtain  [0.5, 99.5, 39.5, 0.5].

Comment: @gciriani but didn't you say that where `df['A'] == 0`, all values of `df['B']` are the same?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your early comment. the function you built has to apply to all identical values of df['B'] as if they were in a group. Therefore pd.Groupby() may be the right way to tackle the problem. I broadened the example to clarify the intent.

Comment: I posted something that works below; it borrows your function and the use of transform, thanks; perhaps you can improve some the way it works.