# Unexpected SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, chained-assignment

I'm running code that [modifies values within a certain threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525942/pandas-calculate-new-value-based-on-cross-reference-with-another-column/55544187#55544187) in a dataframe. I receive a warning that on the surface does not seem warranted:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

My code already uses the a `.loc[row,column]` assignment, therefore I do not understand why the warning suggests that.

```
import pandas as pd
#pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None #disable warning 
#pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment','warn')#or "warn" or "raise"
u = (df 
# Group all forecasts together
     .groupby(by="forecast_id",  sort=False)
# modify only forecasts groups that have smallest value = 0 
     .filter(lambda x: x.value.min() == 0, dropna=False)
# transform values according to a function
     .value.transform( lambda x: (x+0.005).where(x == 0, x-0.005) ) 
     )
# replace the column in the dataframe with the new values except those unaffected
df.loc[pd.notnull(u), "value"] = u
```

The other behavior I could not explain is that as I was playing around with the warning options, once I set the Warning to `None`, even if I reset it back to `"warn"`, there is no warning anymore. Note: my code is used as a function.

---

Edit

A description of what the code does as well an example, is provided in the link at the top; however, my focus here is understanding why why the warning is suggesting an implementation that is already implemented: [Pandas - Calculate New Value Based on Cross Reference with Another Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525942/pandas-calculate-new-value-based-on-cross-reference-with-another-column/55544187#55544187)

Comment: Probably because you have chained `lambda`s that get passed along the chain. This code is close to illegible to me

Comment: `# transform values according to a function` is not helpful as a comment since it doesn't detail anything other than what the following line actually does. You'd hope people reading the code could understand code, so this is actually obfuscation.

Comment: @roganjosh, I've added a description of the code.